# onClick event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons agree and disagree. If I click agree then the page will proceed and if I click disagree then return false stay to the same page. It is a little bit simple but I didn't achieve. I tried below is the sample code. Feel free to tell If anything needs to change.

Can anyone suggest me what might be the problem here?

**JS, CSS, and HTML :**

```js
var termsChk = document.getElementById("agree");
$(".toggle").click(function() {
      if (termsChk.checked === true) {
        alert("Checked!");
      } else {
        //alert("Not Checked!");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 60px;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle+label:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle+label:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left+label:after {
  left: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right+label {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right+label:after {
  left: -100%;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked+label {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 200ms;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked+label:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="agree" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" type="radio">
<label for="agree" class="btn">I agree</label>


<input id="disagree" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" type="radio">
<label for="disagree" class="btn">Disagree</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a JS error, you were not closing the `click` function properly.

```js
var termsChk = document.getElementById("agree");
$(".toggle").click(function() {
      if (termsChk.checked === true) {
        alert("Checked!");
      } else {
        alert("Not Checked!");
        return false;
      }
    });
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 60px;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle+label:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle+label:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left+label:after {
  left: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right+label {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right+label:after {
  left: -100%;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked+label {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 200ms;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked+label:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="agree" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" type="radio">
<label for="agree" class="btn">I agree</label>


<input id="disagree" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" type="radio">
<label for="disagree" class="btn">Disagree</label>
```

Comment: ok..i want if I click disagree button will be active but return false. button bg color not changing to black on active.

Comment: Can you suggest me what missing here?

Comment: @Husna - The problem is the closing `)` at the end of function i.e. `click` was not being closed. And why do you need to return false? Can you please explain?

Comment: page will not proceed to the next page if we click disagree.and when i click disagree background color is not changing why.

Comment: @Husna - You need to handle it with some where else. With the above code snippet, it will be difficult as to how you are painting the next page.

Comment: @Husna - That is because of `return false`. If you remove that line, bg color will start showing up

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using radio group? It's seems you styles radio button to look like button for toggle only. But you can do this by using button also.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
        
        if(this.name === "agree") {
          alert("Agree");
        } else {
          alert("Disagree");
        }
    })
```

```css
body,
html {
  background: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
  border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" name ="agree"> I agree </button> 

<button class="btn" name ="disagree"> Disagree </button>
```